# How to use Firebug's monitor(fn)?

Tags: javascript, firebug, monitor

I read the Firebug documentation about the [Command Line API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API).

Wrote `monitor(functionName)` in the command editor and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. I can't see anything happening... May be my understanding of this command is completely wrong.

I googled but I am still confused how to use this API command?

Comment: @adam @Gaby aka G. Petrioli's code worked. I was just confused the sequence and where can I find the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work fine for me...

Check out the example i made at http://fiddle.jshell.net/gaby/LbCYn/show/

Open the console and put `monitor(toBeMonitored);`. Now each time you click the button it will put in the console that the method was executed..

Comment: thanks. But it is not working for me. Im using Firefox 4, Firebug 1.7.0