# No logging when using monitor() in Firebug

Tags: javascript, logging, firebug, monitor

I tried the following in my JavaScript console in Firebug (v.2.0.12):

```
function square(n) {
  return n*n;
}
monitor(square);
```

Although the console tells me that a monitor has been created successfully, I don't get any logging output once I invoke the function. It works as expected in Chrome's dev tools.

What am I missing? I already checked out the answer under [How to use Firebug's monitor(fn)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537389/how-to-use-firebug-monitorfn/5537487#5537487), but it doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firebug [`monitor()`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Monitor) only works on functions defined within the page's JavaScript code. It does not work on functions dynamically created via Firebug's command line!

So if your page looks like this:

```
<script>
function square(n) {
  return n*n;
}
</script>
<button onclick="square(Math.round(Math.random() * 100))">Create random square</button>
```

Enter this into the command line and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
monitor(square)
```

When you then click the button, the output will look like this:

[image: output of monitor()]

Btw., you can keep track of the monitors you created through the [*Breakpoints* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Breakpoints_Side_Panel) within the [*Script* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel). In there they are listed as *Logged Functions*:

[image: Logged functions being listed within the *Breakpoints* side panel]